Getting GEE data faster
I need country-month level nighttime lights data. I have already printed the data using the minimum example on the https://code.earthengine.google.com/ platform, but the current problem is that it takes more than ten hours to compute and still cannot obtain the data. Later, I switched to using the Python to get the data, but it still takes a long time. All I need is the average value for each month in country level.
Why does it take so long to compute, and how can I improve the code?
Code in https://code.earthengine.google.com/ as follow
// Load VIIRS nighttime lights dataset
var viirs = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG')
            .filterDate('2012-04-01', '2023-11-30'); // Update date range

// Load country boundaries dataset
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Define a function to calculate mean nighttime lights for each country
var calculateMeanLights = function(feature) {
  var countryCo = ee.String(feature.get('country_co'));
  var countryNa = ee.String(feature.get('country_na'));
  var countryGeometry = feature.geometry();
  
  // Map over the image collection to calculate mean nighttime lights for each month
  var meanLightsByMonth = viirs.map(function(image) {
    var yearMonth = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMM');
    var meanLights = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: countryGeometry,
      scale: 500,
      maxPixels: 1e9
    });
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      'country_co': countryCo,
      'country_na': countryNa,
      'year_month': yearMonth,
      'mean_lights': meanLights.get('avg_rad')
    });
  });
  
  return meanLightsByMonth;
};
// Map over the countries and calculate mean nighttime lights for each
var countriesWithLights = countries.map(calculateMeanLights).flatten();


print('Subset of feature collection:', countriesWithLights.limit(10));

// Export a subset of the feature collection to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: countriesWithLights,
  description: 'mean_nighttime_201204_202311',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


Python code is
import ee
import os
import time

ee.Initialize()

# Load country boundaries dataset
countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')

# Define a function to calculate mean nighttime lights for each country for a given month
def calculate_mean_lights_for_month(year, month):
    # Load VIIRS nighttime lights dataset for the specific month
    viirs_monthly = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG') \
                        .filterDate(f'{year}-{month:02d}-01', f'{year}-{month:02d}-01')

    # Define a function to calculate mean nighttime lights for each country
    def calculate_mean_lights(feature):
        country_co = ee.String(feature.get('country_co'))
        country_na = ee.String(feature.get('country_na'))
        country_geometry = feature.geometry()
        
        # Map over the image collection to calculate mean nighttime lights for each country
        def map_over_collection(image):
            year_month = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMM')
            mean_lights = image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                             geometry=country_geometry,
                                             scale=500,
                                             maxPixels=1e9)
            return ee.Feature(None, {
                'country_co': country_co,
                'country_na': country_na,
                'year_month': year_month,
                'mean_lights': mean_lights.get('avg_rad')
            })
        
        mean_lights_by_month = viirs_monthly.map(map_over_collection)
        return mean_lights_by_month
    
    # Map over the countries and calculate mean nighttime lights for each
    countries_with_lights = countries.map(calculate_mean_lights).flatten()

    # Export the table to your local machine
    export_params = {
        'collection': countries_with_lights,
        'description': f'mean_nighttime_{year}{month:02d}',
        'fileFormat': 'CSV'
    }
    
    file_path = f'my_path/mean_nighttime_{year}{month:02d}.csv'
    
    task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(**export_params)
    task.start()

    # Wait for the task to complete
    print(f"Exporting data for {year}-{month:02d}...")
    while task.active():
        print("Task is still active...")
        time.sleep(30)  # Wait for 30 seconds

    print(f"Export for {year}-{month:02d} completed.")

    # Download the exported file to your local machine
    ee.data.getDownloadId(task.id)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path), exist_ok=True)
    ee.data.download(task.id, file_path)

# Perform monthly processing for each month in the specified range
for year in range(2012, 2024):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        calculate_mean_lights_for_month(year, month)

How to improve the code on either platform.

Since the process required to obtain the desired output demands a lot of computing resources, I recommend using a larger scale to perform the calculation. Additionally, you could consider one of the following options to divide the processes, export, and merge outside GEE to avoid the computation limit: 1) dividing the complete period into smaller ones, or 2) filtering the countries by regions (wld_rgn attribute from countries). Also, I find it easier to use reduceRegions instead of mapping over each Feature with reduceRegion.
// Load VIIRS nighttime lights dataset
var viirs = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMCFG')
            .filterDate('2012-04-01', '2023-11-30')  // Update date range
            .select('avg_rad'); // select only the band of interest

// Load country boundaries dataset
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')

// Map over the countries and calculate mean nighttime lights for each
var countriesWithLights = viirs.map(function(image) {
    var yearMonth = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('yyyyMM');
    var meanLights = image.reduceRegions({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      collection: countries,
      scale: 10000,
      tileScale: 16
    });
    return meanLights.map(function(feat){
      // Remove geometries and add yearMonth property
      return ee.Feature(feat).set('geometry', null,
                                  'yearMonth', yearMonth);
    });
  }).flatten();


print('Subset of feature collection:', countriesWithLights.limit(10));

// Export a subset of the feature collection to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: countriesWithLights,
  description: 'mean_nighttime_201204_202311',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

